# How does reserved mail work in gmail? (How can I implement reliable schedulers?)

Tags: gmail, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm curious how Google sends users' mails **at scheduled time**.
Can anyone help me understand how they make it possible in technical terms?

In fact, I'm trying to make a system in my web application that does some action at scheduled time.

This scheduled work must work even when application server is down, so I believe this feature should exist separately from the server.

(All I can think of is batch application, or something similar to mysql event scheduler. I'm not sure if these are reliable enough, as this scheduled work I'm talking about is very critical and should be executed at the promised time)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your emails to send at a later time. Scheduled emails may be sent a few minutes after the scheduled time.
The new Gmail feature lets you schedule emails.Scheduling Gmail messages works from your personal and corporate accounts, and from both your phone and your desktop.

Important: Your emails will be sent based on the timezone you schedule them in.

1. On your computer, go to Gmail
   2.At the top left, click Compose.
2. Create your email.
3. At the bottom left next to "Send," click the dropdown arrow More send options.
4. Click Schedule send.
   Note: You can have up to 100 scheduled emails.

This doesn't need internet, you just need to have an internet connection when scheduling the emails and not at the time you have scheduled that email.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
If email may be sent a few minutes after the scheduled time, then I guess gmail feature is different from the reliable scheduler that I want.

Comment: That is again depending on the time but on whole the concept is reliable as the mail would already be scheduled. If you got the answer could you vote for the answer, it'll be helpful